# True/False last record in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I found a couple of ways to find the last record in a table but how do I set a variable to true if it is the last record and false if it is not?

```
Example 1) SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_Name ORDER BY unique_column DESC 
Example 2) SELECT id from table_Name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

IF @LastRecord = 1

BEGIN
    --do something here     
END
```

Comment: "it is the last record"  Sounds as you are looping the rows. Show all  relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  For instance:

```
select t.*,
       (case when id = max(id) over (order by id desc) then 1 else 0 end) as is_last_id
from t;
```

Comment: OP says _"how do I set a variable to true if it is the last record and false if it is not?"_

Comment: These useful for finding the last record but how do I set a variable to true if it is the last record and false if it is not?

Comment: @user3641053 . . . What do you mean by a "variable"?  This returns a result set with the last record identified using a flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column with no null (example: column_name) and incremental value (Like - auto identity or DateTime), you can use LEAD to identify last row as below. This will select all rows with only value "True" in the last row.

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN LEAD(column_name) OVER(ORDER BY column_name) IS NULL THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
End is_last_column
FROM your_table
```

Comment: OP says _"how do I set a variable to true if it is the last record and false if it is not?"_